# Which recent Ubuntu should I use for Matlab R2011a, Octave 3.6.1 and recent R?

Tags: 64-bit, matlab, r, octave

I wish to install Ubuntu on a new machine 64 bits.

Can you help by telling me which most recent Ubuntu will be compatible and stable with Matlab (R2011a), AND a recent Octave (3.6.1), AND a recent R , all that in 64bits? Do you advise Ubuntu 11.10 or 12.04 ?

Comment: Do you mean 12.04 in the end of your question? 12.10 is far from being ready for even a public beta.

Answer (score 1):

This may answer part of the question… or not at all:

I have MATLAB2011b and Octave 3.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bits), working well.

Comment: thanks for these first precisions ! yes i meant 12.04 as i understood 12.10 is still in the kitchen. I just wondered if 12.04 64 bits is well stable for matlab R11a; Octave 3.6; and R 2.14 with bioconductor 2.9. I read ubuntu 11.10 was compatible wirth matlab R11a and octave 3.6.1. Does that mean that 12.04 is bviously aslo compatible with these versions of the softs?

Comment: What follows is just an opinion: as the focus during the development of 12.04 was "precision", I believe it is strongly backwards compatible. I would definitely go for 12.04 if I were you. Moreover, it seems like you are using Ubuntu for professional purposes: the long-term support (LTS) of 12.04 would be a great plus for you.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab is commercial software. As such, the vendors should have the authoritative idea on what operating system is best for it. You are paying vast amounts of money for it, so get some value for that money and contact them. They might not have tested it on the latest Ubuntu, or maybe they don't even support Ubuntu and you'll have to switch to Redhat Enterprise. Who knows? They do, and you've given them money. Lots of money.

Don't just rely on stuff you read on the internet for commercial software. Get the support from the vendor.